# Dropdownlist of values in a column of database table - MVC Entitiy Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am facing issue in creating a Dropdownlist of values in a column from database table. I want to create a dropdownlist of parent category with values and key which also has null values. Below is the code for columns in my table on front end. I have tried various things like ViewBag, SelectList, MultiSelectList but no luck yet.My Dropdownlist will contain Parent Category ID and ParentCategory values. Category_Int_ID  is the primary key.Kindly help me out. Thanks.

```
List<Category> c1 = db.Categories.ToList();
List<Category> c2 = db.Categories.ToList();

      var catview = from ch in c1
                    join pa in c2 on ch.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID equals pa.CATEGORY_INT_ID into tab1
                    from pa in tab1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    orderby ch.DISPLAY

                              select new Category
                              {
                                  DISPLAY = ch.DISPLAY,
                                  ParentCategory = (pa == null ? string.Empty : pa.DISPLAY),
                                  DESCRIPTION = ch.DESCRIPTION,
                                  CATEGORY_INT_ID = ch.CATEGORY_INT_ID

                              };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Category> c1 = db.Categories.ToList();
                List<Category> c2 = db.Categories.ToList();

                var catview = from ch in c1
                              join pa in c2 on ch.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID equals pa.CATEGORY_INT_ID into tab1
                              from pa in tab1.DefaultIfEmpty()


                              select new Category
                              {
                                  PARENT_CATEGORY_ID = ch.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID,
                                  ParentCategory = pa == null ? "" : pa.DISPLAY,


                              };
                var categ11 = catview.ToList().Where(w=>w.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID !=null).Select(c => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = c.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID.ToString(),
                    Text = c.ParentCategory
                }).Distinct();
                ViewBag.Categories = categ11.ToList().Distinct();
```

In View

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ParentCategoryList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories)
```